# Unable to install XML package in R on CentOS

Tags: r, centos

When I try to install `xml` package in R on CENTOS i recieve such warning:

```
> install.packages("XML")
Installing package into ‘/opt/wpusers/r-mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/XML_3.98-1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1582216 bytes (1.5 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
rm: cannot remove 'a.out.dSYM': Is a directory
a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
checking for xml2-config... no
Cannot find xml2-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/opt/wpusers/r-mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/XML’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp3rqP3n/downloaded_packages’

>
```

My session info is:

```
> session_info()
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio (0.98.1091)         
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Warsaw               

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version   date       source                            
 archivist    1.2       2015-02-12 Github (pbiecek/archivist@d5305be)
 assertthat * 0.1       2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 bitops     * 1.0-6     2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 DBI          0.3.1     2014-09-24 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 devtools     1.7.0     2015-01-17 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 digest     * 0.6.8     2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 dplyr        0.4.0     2015-01-08 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 htmltools  * 0.2.6     2014-09-08 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 httpuv     * 1.3.2     2014-10-23 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 httr       * 0.6.1     2015-01-01 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 lubridate    1.3.3     2013-12-31 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 magrittr   * 1.5       2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 memoise    * 0.2.1     2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 mime       * 0.2       2014-09-26 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 pbapply      1.1-1     2014-05-16 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 plyr       * 1.8.1     2014-02-26 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 R6         * 2.0.1     2014-10-29 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 Rcpp       * 0.11.3    2014-09-29 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 RCurl      * 1.95-4.5  2014-12-28 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 RJSONIO    * 1.3-0     2014-07-28 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 RSQLite      1.0.0     2014-10-25 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 rstudio    * 0.98.1091 2015-01-19 local                             
 rstudioapi * 0.2       2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 shiny        0.10.2.2  2014-12-08 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 stringi      0.4-1     2014-12-14 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 stringr    * 0.6.2     2012-12-06 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                    
 xtable     * 1.7-4     2014-09-12 CRAN (R 3.1.2)
```

Maybe it is a matter of R version?

Comment: I use apt-get sometimes for packages that don't install or need dependencies... sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml

Comment: cory he clearly said CentOS. Which does not have apt-get.

Comment: Your comment is not wrong, what's missing is the correct solution.

Comment: Why don't you read the error message before posting?

Comment: Because I don't understand them. @DirkEddelbuettel answer is great

Comment: "Cannot find xml2-config"  Google "xml2-config".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two problems clearly stated in the output:

1. The first is a warning, you may want to remove `a.out/`:

> ```
> checking for C compiler default output file name... 
> rm: cannot remove 'a.out.dSYM': Is a directory
> a.out
> checking whether the C compiler works... yes
> ```

2. The second is an error and your dealbreaker -- you do **not** have libxml2-dev (or whatever CentOS calls this) installed:

> ```
> checking for xml2-config... no
> Cannot find xml2-config
> ```

Without the XML development tools provided by `libxml2-dev` you simply cannot build the package from source.

Answer (score 1):

if on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install libxml2-devel if your are on Fedora, CentOs or RedHat.

```
dnf install libxml2-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

Install on command line of Centos 7

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel
```

Then

```
install.packages("XML")
```